# How to get information from between brackets in PHP?

Tags: php

So, I'm echoing out information from a api request using Google+ PHP API Client. This is what I get

```
{"access_token":"privateaccesstoken","anotherthing":"stuff"}'
```

How do I go about extracting the privateaccesstoken from that after I echo it out? Is that possible?

Comment: Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being returned in JSON format so you have to decode it to be able to use it:

```
<?php

$str = '{"access_token":"privateaccesstoken","anotherthing":"stuff"}';

$data = json_decode($str);

echo $data->access_token;
```

Answer (score 3):

The API is giving you JSON data, which can be extracted in PHP using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
echo $json['access_token']; // echos 'privateaccesstoken'
```

Passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode` decodes JSON objects to PHP associative arrays, which is usually what you want.

Comment: Giving information about the parameters of the function: +1